# Не поддерживается функция в MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb

Задача:

построить INNER JOIN запрос коллекции book и IntegrationBufferCompleted по _id и abstractDictionaryObject._id соответственно ограничив book-и текущим днем.
В Базе данных MongoDB написал данный запрос, выдает ошибку.

Запрос:

```
SELECT * from 
    book 
    left JOIN IntegrationBufferCompleted as ibc
        ON book._id=ibc.abstractDictionaryObject_id 
         WHERE DATEDIFF(day, book.createDate, GETDATE()) = 0
```

Ошибка:

```
Unsupported function: DATEDIFF
```

Как сделать, чтобы фунция стала работать. Если никак, то какая может быть альретнатива?

Comment: а что `mongodb` поддерживает `sql`? o_O

Comment: А вроде пишут есть `datediff`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/

Comment: по поводу поддерживает sql или нет - я могу ошибаться, но как мне кажется простые запросы он выполняет, а насчет datediff спасибо